# How can i take that input value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm having a big problem in trying to get the value of these inputs and associates them to the object "book" when you click " Book Now! "

No matter where I declare the object in js , it just does not work. 
It was for the object like this:

```js
            $scope.book = {
                bday_i : new date(day, month, year),
                bday_f : book(bday_i),
                bfrom : getHours(bday_i),
                buntil : getHours(bday_i),
                bresource : "Small meeting room ",
                bmember : "Lucas Gabriel da Costa",
                busercredit : ("4 hours left of", book(bresource)),
                bcoment : "Test"
            }
```

And i try to get the values ​​and assign them to variables like this:

```js
            $scope.book.bday_i = myForm.day_i.value;
            $scope.book.bday_f = myForm.day_f.value;
            $scope.book.bfrom = myForm.from.value;
            $scope.book.buntil = myForm.until.value;
            $scope.book.bresource = myForm.resource.value;
            $scope.book.bmember = myForm.member.value;
            $scope.book.busercredit = myForm.usercredit.value;
            $scope.book.bcoment = myForm.coment.value;
            $modalInstance.close(result);
```

```js
      $scope.dayClick = function (date, jsEvent, view, value) {
           $scope.newEventDate = date;


        
            
      var
           
               t =
               '<div class="modal-header">' +
    '<h5>New booking</h5>' + 
    '</div>' +
    '<form ng-model="myForm" name="myForm" id="myForm">'+
    '<div class="modal-body" name="box" >' + 
    '<p>Time: ' + ' ' + '<pre >' + ' Initial date:' +
    '<input id="day_i" class="form-control" type="date" name="day_i" ng-model="day_i" type="text" min = "dia_hj" value="dia_hj"  required />  ' +
    ' Final date:' +
    '<input id="day_f" class="form-control" type="date" name="day_f" ng-model="day_f" type="text" min = "day_i" value="dia_hj"  required />  ' +
    ' From:' +
    ' <input id="from" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from" type="time" min = "getHours()"  value="" required  />' +
    ' Until' +
    ' <input id="until" class="form-control" name="until" ng-model="until" type="time" min = "myForm.from.value" value="" required  /> </pre></p>' +
    '<p> Resource:' +
    ' <pre><input id="resource" class="form-control" name="resource" ng-model="resource" type="text" placeholder ="Ex: Small Meeting Room" value="" required /></pre></p> ' +
    '<p> Member: ' +
    ' <pre><input id="member" class="form-control " name="member" ng-model="member" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Lucas Gabriel da Costa" value="" required />  </pre></p>  ' +
    '<p> User credit:' +
    ' <pre><input id="usercredit" class="form-control" name="usercredit" ng-model="usercredit" type="text"  placeholder="Ex: 4 hours included(Small meeting Room)" value=""  required /></pre></p>' +
    'Note:' +
    '<pre><textarea id="coment" ng-model = "coment" name="coment" rows="4" cols="46" placeholder="Insert ur comment"></textarea></pre></form>' +
    // validação:
    '<div ng-hide= " myForm.day_i.$pristine">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.day_i.$error.required "       class="alert alert-danger">  The INITIAL DATE camp is required.      Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span></div>   ' +
    '<div ng-hide= " myForm.day_f.$pristine">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.day_f.$error.required || (myForm.day_f.value <= myForm.day_i.value)" class="alert alert-danger">  The FINAL DATE camp is required.      Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span></div>   ' +
    '<div ng-hide =" myForm.from.$pristine">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.from.$error.required "        class="alert alert-danger">  The FROM camp is required.     Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span></div>   ' +
    '<div ng-hide =" myForm.until.$pristine">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.until.$error.required || myForm.until.value < myForm.from.value" class="alert alert-danger">  The UNTIL camp is required.    Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span></div>   ' +
    '<div ng-hide="  myForm.resource.$pristine ">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.resource.$error.required "    class="alert alert-danger">  The RESOURCE camp is required. Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span></div>   ' +
    '<div ng-hide= " myForm.member.$pristine">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.member.$error.required "      class="alert alert-danger">  The MEMBER camp is required.   Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span></div>   ' +
    '<div ng-hide="  myForm.usercredit.$pristine">' +
    '<span  ng-show="myForm.usercredit.$error.required "  class="alert alert-danger">  The CREDIT camp is required.   Or a invalid value was inserted    <br/><br/>  </span> </div>  ' +
   
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
    '<button ng-click="close(result)" id="b1" ng-model="b1" name="b1" class="btn btn-danger " >Close</button>' + //botão de fechar
    '<button  ng-click="close2(okay) " id="b2" ng-model="b2" name="b2" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="myForm.usercredit.$pristine || myForm.day.$pristine || myForm.from.$pristine || myForm.until.$pristine || myForm.resource.$pristine || myForm.member.$pristine "> Book Now! </button>' +
    '</div>'; 
       

           var
          
               modalInstance = $modal.open({
               template: t,
               controller: 'TestDialogController',
               backdrop: "true",
               resolve: {
                   event: function () {
                       return $scope.newEventDate;
                   },
                   stage: function () {
                       return $scope.stage;
                   }
               }
               });
    
             modalInstance.okay.then(
                function () {
                     alert('');
               
;               
           });
      
           modalInstance.result.then(
   function (result) {
      //console.log('called $modalInstance.close()');
       alert(result);

       $scope.addEvent();
   },
   function (result) {
       //console.log('called $modalInstance.dismiss()');

       $scope.addEvent();
   }
  );
       
       };
    app.controller('TestDialogController', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.close = function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $modalInstance.close(result);
        }});
```

```html
<div class="container pad-35">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Space Header  -->
        <venue-header title="{{ venue_title }}" nav="header"></venue-header>
        <!-- Dashboard -->
        <div class="col-md-12 pull-left" ng-cloak>
            <section id="directives-calendar" ng-controller="CalendarCtrl">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span8">
                          
                            <tabset>
                                <tab select="renderCalender('myCalendar1');">
                                    <tab-heading>
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Calendar One
                                    </tab-heading>
                                      <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                        <center><p class="pull-right lead">Calendar One View Options</p></center>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                             <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="changeView('agendaDay', 'myCalendar1')">AgendaDay</button>
                                             <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="changeView('agendaWeek', 'myCalendar1')">AgendaWeek</button>
                                             <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="changeView('month', 'myCalendar1')">Month</button>        
                                             <!--select para definir o resource a ser usado no controler js-->
 
                                          </div>
                                          <p class="textalign1">
                                               <center>
                                                   <select id="select-lucas" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-success " ng-model="model.id" convert-to-number>
                                                       <option value="" selected="selected" onclick="">small meeting room</option>
                                                       <option value="1" selected="selected" onclick="">medium meeting room</option>
                                                       <option value="2" selected="selected" onclick="">Big meeting room</option>
                                                       <option value="3" selected="selected" onclick="">Giant meeting room</option>
                                                   </select>
                                               </center>
                                          </p>
                                               
                                           
                                           
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="calendar ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
                                 
                                 
                                </tab>
                                
                            </tabset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[The result is this pop up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX03T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is defined in the modal which have his own controller and his own scope.

So when you do

```
 ng-model="until"
```

In your input, this is binding a variable "until" ont eh scope modal's controller.

so if you want to build an object you ave to do like this in the modal controller :

```
var book = {};
book.buntil = $scope.until;
```

Same for every fields.
After if you want to display that books to the main view you could use an event that is emitted and listen on the $rootscope.

I don't know which modal library you use so i can't say if the scope generated if a child of the other.

Comment: I am using actualy bootstrap

Comment: If i remember well, bootstrap create a child scope. This mean if you defined a $scope.book and make sure it's iniialized to null or whatever before creating the modal in your main controller and do a $scope.book.until = 'toto', then the value will be in your mainController. I already went to some trouble because of that. I even tryed to use the resolve in order to pass the object from the mainCOntroller to the modalOne and still had trouble : i had to use angular.merge function to be sure to have an independent copy of the object

Comment: Now i changed the database and the problem now is with php :D